# Как указать в google sheets котировки с google finance usdrub из Мовковской биржи?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

MCX это MOEX Московская биржа
LKOH это бумага Лукойл

На примере с акциями все работает:

=GoogleFinance("MCX:LKOH")

А вот в валютой уже сложнее:

Все работает но тут котировка не понятно от какой биржи...

=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDEUR")

Пробую добавить путь в Московской но это не помогает.

=GoogleFinance("MCX:CURRENCY:USDEUR")

Как получить котировки конкретно от MOEX?
Желательно пару USD_RUB_TOD

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В листинг этой формулы попадает все что угодно, кроме того, что надо. Примеров таких масса, и этот не исключение. Удивительно, что она (формула) вообще что-то внятное возвращает по `MCX`. Проблема в том, что не все пути поддерживаются, не все данные возвращаются, и часть информации генерируется автоматически ([при неполных путях](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=ru)) так, что конечному пользователю никогда не понять наверняка, откуда эти цифры.

С каждым годом работа формулы улучшается, Гугл очевидно что-то делает. Но все это еще очень далеко от идеала. Единственный более-менее внятный способ поправить ситуацию - писать фидбэк из меню Таблицы.

*При написании запроса на фичу будьте кратки, излагайте мысль по-существу, без сослагательного наклонения. Можете писать по-русски, они и такое читают.*